# Creating three-state Markov chain plot

Tags: r, markov-chains

I have following dataframe with there states: angry, calm, and tired. The dataframe below provides individual cases of transition of one state into another.

```
pre<-cbind(c(rep("tired",100),rep("angry",100),rep("calm",100)))
post<-cbind(c(rep("tired",50),rep("angry",70),rep("calm",100),rep("tired",80)))
df<-cbind(pre,post)
df<-as.data.frame(df)
colnames(df)<-c("pre","post")
```

What I would like to achieve is buidling a Markov's chain plot for three states that is also called "playground" and looks like this:

[image]

How would I do it in R?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the `markovchain` package, using the `plot` method in `diagram`.

Let's first compute the transition probability matrix from your `df`

```
states<-c("tired","angry","calm")

probsCase<-function(i,j){
  sum(as.character(df$pre)==states[i] & as.character(df$post)==states[j])/sum(as.character(df$pre)==states[i])
}

transitionMatrix<-outer(1:3,1:3,Vectorize(probsCase))
colnames(transitionMatrix)<-states
rownames(transitionMatrix)<-states
```

Now use `markovchain` to initialize and plot the matrix

```
library(markovchain)
markovChain <- new("markovchain", states=states, transitionMatrix=transitionMatrix)
plot(markovChain,package="diagram")
```

EDIT:

If you have troubles installing the `markovchain` package, we can actually not use it and use directly the `diagram` package, which needs just `transitionMatrix`

```
library(diagram)
plotmat(transitionMatrix,relsize=0.7)
```

You can then tweak the appearance according to your taste using the options in `plotmat`

Comment: thanks for your response, I successfully got to the transitionMatrix, but have trouble installing the package `markovchain`, specifically its dependency `RCurl`. I have I R version 3.2.3, running on Crunchbang Linux Waldorf. How did you install it? Would you be able to at least addend your answer to post how the plot looks like? Thanks again.

Comment: thanks! it works but for some reason right and upper margins of the plot are beyond the R graphics device. Is there a way to substitute numbers 1, 2, and 3 with the states  "tired","angry","calm" in the plot?

Comment: For the first one, change `relsize` argument in `plotmat`. For the second you need to rename rows and columns of transition matrix. The edit will play the trick

Comment: is there a way to add color to the tree state circles in the plot?

Comment: I am not an expert of the `plotmat` function, but I think that going through the arguments in the documentation should help you find it

Comment: @ I figured it out, for others, adding `box.col=c("red","green","blue")` will work. Thanks again.

Comment: proportions were not adding up to 1 upon exit, but upon entry, I asked a separate question regarding this - would you be able to take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36581441/proportions-in-markov-chain-do-not-add-up-to-1/36581569#36581569