# How to read a transition matrix into Cytoscape for Markov Chain modelling?

Tags: r, format, transition, markov-chains, cytoscape

I would like to read a transition matrix into Cytoscape for Markov Chain modelling. As an example, I am borrowing below transition matrix (including R code) from this post:
[Creating three-state Markov chain plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36574814/creating-three-state-markov-chain-plot)

How can Cytoscape read such `transitionMatrix`?

Thank you.

**Format of the transition matrix**

This is what the transitionMatrix looks like:

```
       tired angry calm
 tired   0.5   0.5  0.0
 angry   0.0   0.2  0.8
 calm    0.8   0.0  0.2
```

**R code**

```
 pre<-cbind(c(rep("tired",100),rep("angry",100),rep("calm",100)))
 post<-cbind(c(rep("tired",50),rep("angry",70),rep("calm",100),rep("tired",80)))
 df<-cbind(pre,post)
 df<-as.data.frame(df)
 colnames(df)<-c("pre","post")
 states<-c("tired","angry","calm")
 probsCase<-function(i,j){
   sum(as.character(df$pre)==states[i] & 
   as.character(df$post)==states[j])/sum(as.character(df$pre)==states[i])
 }
 transitionMatrix<-outer(1:3,1:3,Vectorize(probsCase))
 colnames(transitionMatrix)<-states
 rownames(transitionMatrix)<-states
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an app called aMatReader that will allow you to read in adjacency matrices.

-- scooter